# jQuery toggle opacity with animate function

Tags: jquery

i wrote a jquery function and from there i try to toggle opacity with animate function but my code is not working. can anyone tell me where is the fault. thanks

```
            jQuery.fn.blindToggle = function (speed, easing, callback) {
            var _opacity = 0;
            var h = this.height() + parseInt(this.css('paddingTop')) + parseInt(this.css('paddingBottom'));
            $(this).toggle(function () {
                _opacity = 0;
            },
            function () {

                _opacity = 1;
            });
            alert(_opacity);
            return this.animate({ opacity: _opacity,
                marginTop: parseInt(this.css('marginTop')) < 0 ? 0 : -h
            }, speed, easing, callback);
        };
```

Comment: Add the style using css and use toggleClass instead.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? It seems fine for me

Comment: i alert opacity and it always say 0 not 1.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/YdnLd/8/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[jQuery's `animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) has a shortcut for what you're trying to do:

```
$(this).animate({"opacity": "toggle"});
```

Then you don't need to implement that logic yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`toggle` only works for element attributes, not for var values. This case you can simple do the following.

`_opacity = _opacity == 0 ? 1 : 0;`

*Demos*:

- [using toggle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLdT5/1/) does not work
- [using If](http://jsfiddle.net/hLdT5/) works
- [using toggleClass](http://jsfiddle.net/hLdT5/2/) works

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has sweet function

```
.fadeToggle()
```

[Documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)